# adding records to a table using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I send out a newsletter each month and would like to record the contact id, date sent in a separate table.    This table will record a history of all the newsletter sent.  What is the best way to do this...Append to table or just create a do loop and add new records?

Comment: Well, *'add new records'* is just another way of saying *'Append to table'* so I don't think it matters what you call it.

Comment: `Recordset.AddNew` is preferable because it protects against SQL injection.  Alternatively, you could write a parameterized query.

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty easy.  Now, you didn't say is you are appending records into Access, or SQL Server, or something else.  The example below assumes you are using Access, but you can easily modify the code just slightly to insert into any kind of structured database.

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Set dbs = OpenDatabase("Full path to your db")

'You can then "execute" a SQL statement:

dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO Employees(Name, Number) VALUES('" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value & "','" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3") & "')"
```